# Getting a Spring resource

Tags: spring, resources, path, relative-path

I'm trying to read a css file with the Resources provided by Spring.

My application looks like this:

- src

  - src/com herer my classes inside packages
- WebContent

  - WebContent/resources/style/myCSS.css --> the css I want to read
  - WebContent/WEB-INF --> here is my application-context.xml

I can get the css and read it by doing something like this:

```
UrlResource file = new UrlResource("http://localhost:8080/myApp/resources/style/myCSS.css");
```

but it depends on the server and aplication names.
I've tried to do it by other implementations of Resource Interface, but the file is not found cause I can't find out how to wite the path. I've tried with this:

FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource("/WebContent/resources/style/myCSS.css");

I also tried with wildcards, but it doesn't find the file either.

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/WEB-INF/application-context-core.xml");
Resource file = ctx.getResource("file:**/myCSS.css");
```

How should I write the path to get the css.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with 
ServletContextResource file = new ServletContextResource(servletContext, "/resources/style/myCSS.css");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [`ServletContextResource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextResource.html). You can construct it passing the `ServletContext` and the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

What about `new ClassPathResource("/resources/style/myCSS.css")`?